# Sudo apt install doesn't work.My packages is broken

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I'm having way too many issues with my computer right now, but I will start with trying to fix my WiFi. So I tried to install net-tools, but then this happened.

```
    patrick@patrick-Swift-SF315-51G:~$ sudo apt install net-tools
[sudo] password for patrick: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried this: apt --fix-broken install & apt-get -f install - received the same answer.

```
patrick@patrick-Swift-SF315-51G:~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I also have received a notification from my Package Manager:
**The package system is broken**

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so, disable them since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore, run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
  libc6-dbg: Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
    libc6-dev: Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
               Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is installed
```

So my question is, how can I fix the broken packages and use Sudo apt-get install again?

Thank you for your time.

Edit:
I tried sudo apt-get clean & sudo apt-get update
Then I tried Sudo apt-get -f install, same result.

```
    Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried to sudo dpkg --configure -a; and received this

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-dbg:amd64:
 libc6-dbg:amd64 depends on libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.1.

dpkg: error processing package libc6-dbg:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-dev:amd64:
 libc6-dev:amd64 depends on libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.1.

dpkg: error processing package libc6-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6-dbg:amd64
 libc6-dev:amd64
```

Comment: Run that fix-broken command again, but prepend the command with `sudo`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following workflow

> sudo apt-get clean

> sudo apt-get update

> sudo apt-get -f install

> sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: I'm sorry, It just returns back to the error:

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

And when I tried dpkg --configure -a, it shows which packages are broken:
dpkg: error processing package libc6-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6-dbg:amd64
 libc6-dev:amd64

Comment: It might be diffucult to read in the comment, so I will add it in the Question